# Set axios authorization header depends on store changes

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am new to Vue (I am a react person) and I am having this problem.

axios.js

```
import store from '../../store/index';
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const token = store.getters.auth.token;

export default  axios.create({
baseURL: API_URL,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
 }
})
```

store/index.js

```
import auth from './modules/auth'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({

  state: {},
  getters : {},
  mutations: {},
  actions:{},

  modules: {
    auth
  },
  strict: debug,
})
```

modules/auth

```
import { AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_GUEST } from '../actions/auth'
import axios from '../../util/axios/axios'
import Vue from "vue";

const state = {
  token: localStorage.token || '',
};

const getters = {
  token: state => state.token
};

const actions = {
  [AUTH_GUEST]: async ({commit}) => {
    await axios.post('auth/register',)
      .then(response => {
        commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};

const mutations = {
  [AUTH_SUCCESS]: (state, resp) => {
    state.token = resp.data.token;
  },
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
}
```

when trying to get the store from `store/index` it returns `undefined`.
probably the axios has been called before the store has been initialized.

but how can I deal with it?

the flow of the app is.

```
user register->get token->update store with this token->add to the axios header.
```

so for now on, all calls to the api will have the token provided.

Comment: I suspect the problem is from the auth module. The store will be already initialized when the axios request is made. Do you get undefined on store object or on store.getters.auth.token ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be careful with [Vue's reactivity caveats](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) which affect Vuex aswell. In your case, you're adding a new property inside an object in a mutation.

Back to the main issue, your `axios.js` file is being executed before the Store instance is built, that's why you cannot access to it and you get undefined.

What I'd do is:

`axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

export default (store) => axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${store.getters.auth.token}`
  }
});
```

and then in your main file, where you have the main Vue instantiation I'd just run the function there, exporting the return of that function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. By doing your way I still get the store as undefined.